# openvpn ubuntu 16.04 vpn manager keeps reconnecting with expired password

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, openvpn, networkmanager

ubuntu 16.04
OpenVPN
I did :

> sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome

all good, connect to VPN.

The issue starts when I lost a connection (due to connection expiration), then it **tries to reconnect** to the VPN server n times a second with an already **expired password** and as result, I got banned from the corporate network.

**Q: how to prevent network-manager reconnect automatically but rather ask for the password?**

Answer (score -1):

Oh.. it took me a while to figure out.
It is more UX issue.

There is a small exclamation(then question) mark close to the password filed int he network manager, click on which you will get a pop up.. with "do not store password" as an option. :)

In the config file, in: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, as I figured out later, it is:

`password-flags=2` (very readable! :)

[image]